# WP_query return more results than SQL query. post_count > found_posts

Tags: wp-query

IF specified fields parameter as 'ids' then my WP_query working ok (but i want all fileds).

```
    $query3 = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => array('post'),
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'fields'         => 'ids',
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'column' => 'post_modified_gmt',
            'after'  => '1 month ago'
            )
        )
));

  [request] => SELECT   x_posts.ID FROM x_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND ( 
   x_posts.post_modified_gmt > '2017-08-27 12:02:06'
 ) AND x_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (x_posts.post_status = 'publish')  
 ORDER BY x_posts.post_date DESC 
[post_count] => 14
[found_posts] => 14
[max_num_pages] => 0
[max_num_comment_pages] => 0
```

If i don't use fields parameter. I get.

```
    [post_count] => 215
    [found_posts] => 14
```

But SQL query is correct.

```
[request] => SELECT   x_posts.* FROM x_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND ( 
   x_posts.post_modified_gmt > '2017-08-27 12:02:06'
 ) AND x_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (x_posts.post_status = 'publish')  
 ORDER BY x_posts.post_date DESC
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: A little confused by your syntax. Normally when you use `WP_Query` you specify `post_status = 'publish'` right in WP_Query. So unless I am misunderstanding perhaps that's the issue, you just need to specify that you only want published posts?

Answer (score 0):

post_status='publish' is default yo WP_Query so you not need specified.
As you can see real SQL query is ok. 
And all returned results are with status publish.
looks like that only post_modified_gmt > 'xxx' is not respect.

Currenly use construction with

```
 'fields'         => 'ids',
```

so get only 14 post id's and next

```
 foreach($query3->posts as $id) {
                $post = get_post($id);
 // ...
```

but i don't know if it is optimal way